# Transfer file to pc from embedded linux device via serial communications

Tags: embedded, debugging, serial-port

I'm working on an AT91SAM9G20.  I'm connected to AT91SAM9G20 via the debug port using `rs232` serial communications.

It has Linux `version 3.4.8` but does not appear to have any of the common file transfer utilities listed around the web e.g. `rx, rb, rz`.

There is a data connection to the web and I can `wget` files but there is no make on the board so I cannot build them.

Is there a way to get a file from the embedded linux device via the serial port.

edit 1: It does have minicom, so that may be an option?
edit 2: minicom list rz, rb, rx, kermit in /usr/bin but they are not there.  It doesn't work when executed.  In the below good screenshot, the yellow portion does not appear on my board.

[image: minicom]

Comment: do you found a solution ? I have the same need ;-)

Comment: I used curl as there was a wireless connection, split the file into smaller files and curl it up.  However, I found another way uuencode.